# List out all the definable set in given model

Tags: logic, model-theory

The problem says:

List all the definable subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ in ($\mathbb R$,<) with formulas.

And I found $x<y$, $y<x$ and $x=y$  are desired one. But, I want to say that any subset which could made up by them is also definable. For example, less than or equal to is also desired one, but I want to say that not just it is definable but it is definable since it is made by $x<y$, $y<x$ and $x=y$. I intuitively think that there're many definable sets like $\leq $ above. So, my question is that:

How can I express all of such definable sets by $x<y$, $y<x$ and $x=y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to note that the only thing that matters to whether some sequence of elements satisfies a formula over $(\mathbb R,<)$ is how the elements stand to each other with respect to $<$ and $=$.  A little more precisely,

- if $(\mathbb R, <)\models \phi (a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ and if $((b_1,\ldots,b_k),<)$ is isomorphic to $((a_1,\ldots,a_k),<)$,
  then $(\mathbb R,<)\models \phi(b_1,\ldots,b_k)$.

This is routine to show by induction on formulas.

It follows that the relations definable over $(\mathbb R,<)$ are just those $R$ such that...

1. if $(a,a)\in R$ then $(b,b)\in R$ for all $b\in \mathbb R$
2. if $(a,b)\in R$ with $a<b$ then $(c,d)\in R$ for all $c,d\in \mathbb R$ such that $c<d$
3. if $(a,b)\in R$ with $a>b$ then $(c,d)\in R$ for all $c,d\in \mathbb R$ such that $c>d$.

There are eight such relations: $=$, $\neq$, $<$, $>$, $\leq$, $\geq$, $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$, and $\emptyset$.

Comment: How the conditions of R you give  follows from Isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Suppose $R$ is definable, so that there's a $\phi$ such that $R=\{(a,b):(\mathbb R,<)\models \phi(a,b)\}$.  Now consider for example the condition 2.  Suppose $(a,b)\in R$, that $a<b$ and that $c<d$.  Then $((a,b),<)$ is isomorphic to $((c,d),<)$, and also $(\mathbb R,<)\models \phi(a,b)$.  By the observation about $<$-isomorphic sequences, it follows that $(\mathbb R,<)\models \phi(c,d)$ and hence that $(c,d)\in R$.

Comment: Then how could I show those are isomorphic? is it okay to take a automorphism of R(real) or consider a isomorphism h such that h(a)=c and h(b)=d in your example?.

Comment: Saying $((a_1,\ldots,a_k),<)$ and $((b_1,\ldots,b_k),<)$ are isomorphic is a short way of saying that how $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ stand to each other with respect to $<$ and $=$ is exactly how $b_1,\ldots,b_k$ stand to each other with respect to $<$ and $=$.  That is, it's to say that $a_i=a_j$ iff $b_i=b_j$, and $a_i<a_j$ iff $b_i<b_j$, and $a_i>a_j$ iff $b_i>b_j$ for all $i,j$ between $1$ and $k$.

Comment: So, if $a<b$ and $c<d$, then $((a,b),<)$ and $((c,d),<)$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally I fully understand it!!!